# How can I cash a US cashier check in Sweden?

Tags: check, international, international-transfer, sweden, cashier-check

I have a cashier check from the US. I live in Sweden, and the Swedish bank will not accept it. What can I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to wire a check internationally (US to China) without a bank account?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/158088/how-to-wire-a-check-internationally-us-to-china-without-a-bank-account)

Comment: A.) Who sent you the cashier check?  B.) Why did they send it to you?

Comment: Do you have a US bank account?